# Entity Framework Joining table to another table through a Like how to convert SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Evening

I have a rather ugly SQL statement I am trying to convert into Linq (.net 6 (core)) but I am struggling to convert it, the error I am getting is:

```
The LINQ expression 'CROSS APPLY (Projection Mapping:
        CategoryId -> c.Id
        CategoryName -> c.Name
    SELECT c.Id AS CategoryId, c.Name AS CategoryName
    FROM categories AS c
    WHERE (c.lft == (c.rgt - 1)) && (e.CleanDescription LIKE ('%' + COALESCE(c.Name, '')) + '%')
    UNION ALL
    Projection Mapping:
        CategoryId -> c0.id
        CategoryName -> c0.name
    SELECT c0.id AS CategoryId, c0.name AS CategoryName
    FROM category_labels AS c0
    LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON c0.categoryId == c1.Id
    WHERE ((c1.lft == (c1.rgt - 1)) || (Equal(c1.lft) && Equal(c1.rgt))) && (e.CleanDescription LIKE ('%' + c0.name) + '%')
) AS t
' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Can anyone help?

```sql
SELECT  r.id, r.Name,r.Description, IF (MAX(r.percentageMatch) < 65 || r.CategoryId IS NULL, "fb319c1d-13a9-47e1-a5dc-0e4c4a9a7c13",r.CategoryId), r.CategoryName, MAX(r.percentageMatch)
FROM (
SELECT ei.Id, ei.Name, ei.Description, ei.CleanDescription,c.Id as CategoryId, c.Name as CategoryName, ((length(ei.CleanDescription)-(locate(c.name, ei.CleanDescription -1))/length(ei.CleanDescription) * 100) * 0.4) + ((length(c.Name)/length(ei.CleanDescription)* 100) *0.6) as PercentageMatch
from (SELECT e.Id, e.Name, e.Description, e.CleanDescription FROM equipments e WHERE e.EquipmentCategoryId = "fb319c1d-13a9-47e1-a5dc-0e4c4a9a7c13" OR e.EquipmentCategoryId = null ) ei
left join (
            select c.Id, c.Name
            FROM categories c
            WHERE c.Lft = c.rgt-1
            UNION
            select c.Id, l.Name
            FROM category_labels l
            inner join categories c on c.Id = l.categoryId
            WHERE c.Lft = c.rgt-1
) c on  ei.CleanDescription like CONCAT("%",c.Name,"%")
)r
GROUP BY r.id, r.Name, r.Description
```

I have tried the following to no success and just wondering if it easier to use Store Procedure or go for RawSql execution?

My Linq currently looks like

```cs
_db.Equipments.Include(i => i.EquipmentCategory) 
    .SelectMany(m =>
        _db.Categories
        .Where(n => n.Left == n.Right - 1 && EF.Functions.Like(m.CleanDescription, "%"+n.Name+"%"))
        .Select(s => new { CategoryId = s.Id, CategoryName = s.Name })
        .Concat(
            _db.CategoryLabels
            .Where(n => n.Category.Left == n.Category.Right - 1 && EF.Functions.Like(m.CleanDescription, "%" + n.Name + "%"))
            .Select(s => new { CategoryId = s.Id, CategoryName = s.Name })
            ).Select(s=> new { Equipment = m, Category = s, Percentage = (((m.CleanDescription.Length - (m.CleanDescription.IndexOf(s.CategoryName) - 1)) / m.CleanDescription.Length * 100 )* 0.4) +
        ((s.CategoryName.Length / m.CleanDescription.Length * 100) * 0.6)
            })
        ).ToList();
```

**Update 1**

I tried Svyatoslav suggestion but I am still getting the following error: Nullable object must have a value

I have rewritten the query as below but not sure what I am missing.

```
(from equipment in _db.Equipments
                         from c in (
                                        (from catInner in _db.Categories
                                         where catInner.Left == catInner.Right - 1// && equipment.CleanDescription == catInner.Name
                                         select new Category
                                         {
                                             Id = catInner.Id,
                                             Left = catInner.Left,
                                             Right = catInner.Right,
                                             Name = catInner.Name,
                                             RootId = catInner.RootId,
                                             ParentId = catInner.ParentId,
                                             Level = catInner.Level,
                                             Updated = catInner.Updated,
                                             Created = catInner.Created
                                         })
                                       .Union(
                                        from catLabel in _db.CategoryLabels
                                        where catLabel.Category.Left == catLabel.Category.Right - 1// && equipment.CleanDescription == catLabel.Name
                                        select new Category {
                                        Id = catLabel.Id, Left = catLabel.Category.Left, 
                                            Right = catLabel.Category.Right, 
                                            Name = catLabel.Category.Name, 
                                            RootId = catLabel.Category.RootId, 
                                            ParentId = catLabel.Category.ParentId,
                                            Level = catLabel.Category.Level, 
                                            Updated = catLabel.Category.Updated, Created = catLabel.Category.Created
                                        })
                                       ).Where(c => equipment.CleanDescription == c.Name).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          let parent = c
                          where equipment.EquipmentCategoryId == null || equipment.EquipmentCategoryId == Guid.Empty || equipment.EquipmentCategoryId == CategoryId.Unkown
                          select  new { Equipment = equipment, Category = parent }  
                          ).ToList();
```

Comment: In your case, I suggest the best choice is adding the procedure but how I can see you don't use any parameters, so you can write view to get data.

Comment: If you have joins - use Query Syntax.. This query is definitely convertible to LINQ. For LEFT JOIN via Like, use the following technique: `from t1 in table1 from t2 in table2.Where(t2 =>. t1.Description.Like(...)).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  Tried your suggestion (Update 1 in my original post) but I still can't seem to get this working.

Comment: Any exception? Why you have used `let`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  That was accidentally left in I was simply trying something I saw online.  If I don't try to select anything from C then it works but as soon as I try to do Select new {Equipment = equipment, Category = c}  it comes up with  Nullable object must have a value